# Missing Activities tab when viewing contacts

Tags: contacts, 4.6

When viewing a contact, there is no "Activities" tab in the list of tabs. Is this a configurable setting somewhere?

In other words, is there a way to add this tab to the Contact page?

Running CiviCRM 4.6.17

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is configurable at this path civicrm/admin/setting/preferences/display?reset=1 which is found from Administer > Customise > Display Preferences.

The top section is called Viewing Contacts and has a checkbox for eg Activities